# Low power design for adders

Tags: verilog

I have to implement a circuit that performs A+B+C+D serially.

A and B are added using the first adder, the result is added to C using the second adder and finally the result is added to D using the third adder, one after the other.

The problem is, in order to make the design low power. I have to turn off the other two adders which are not in use. All I can think is Enable and Disable signals, but this causes latency issues.

How do I synthesize  this in in an effective manner in verilog?

A,B,C,D may change every clock cycle. a start signal is used to indicate when a new calculation is required.

Comment: Any related material would be useful

Comment: What do you mean by 'serially'? If it's real bit-serial you use a single one-bit adder and shift all the bits through it - minimal power, high latency, nothing to turn off, relatively easy to code. If you actually have to disable two real n-bit adders to save power then you have to turn off the clock to them. Enable and disable signals won't in general help (much), if they simply gate data.

Comment: Its an 8 bit adder, carry out can be ignored

Comment: will using Verilog events to trigger the adders prove more effective ??

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw No Verilog events are not synthesizable.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your adder has been implied via `sum = A + B;`. For area optimisation why do you not share a single adder unit. A+B in CLK1, SUM+C in CLK2, SUM+D in CLK3. Then you have nothing to disable or clock gate.

The majority of power is used when values change, so zeroing inputs when not used can actually increase power by creating unnecessary toggles. As adders are combinatorial logic all we can do to save power for a given architecture is hold values stable, this could be done through the use of clock gate cells controlling/sequencing input and output flip-flops clks.

**Update**

With the information that a new calculation may be required every clock cycle, and there is an enable signal called `start`. Th question made reference to adding them serially ie :

```
sum1 = A + B;
sum2 = sum1 + C;
sum3 = sum2 + D;
```

Since the result is calculated potentially every clock cycle they are all on or all off. The given serialisation (which is all to be executed in parallel) has 3 adders stringed together (ripple path of 3 adders). if we refactor to :

```
sum1 = A + B;
sum2 = C + D;
sum3 = sum1 + sum2;
```

Or ripple path is only 2 adders deep allowing a quicker settling time, which implies less ripple or transients to consume power.

I would be tempted to do this all on 1 line and allow the synthesis tool to optimise it.

```
sum3 = A + B + C + D;
```

For power saving I would turn on auto clock gating when synthesising and use a structure that worked well with this technique:

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    sum3 <= 'b0;
  end
  else begin
    if (start) begin //no else clause, means this signal can clk gate the flop
      sum3 <= A + B + C + D;
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: A part of problem destination is to have three adders to increase the throughput and disable them when not in use.It makes sense in using one adder, but , the data -A,B,C,D is flows in randomly i.e can flow every clock or may have delay of few clock cycles

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw Are any of the input A,B,C,D more likely to change than the other, this could effect power by grouping static values together. say A and D hardly change, sum1(A+D) + sum2(B+C). Here we minimise the  toggles in sum1, saving power.

Comment: A start signal from the test bench indicates the incoming data

Comment: All are likely to change every time the data comes in

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37098/discussion-between-morgan-and-trafalgar-law)